# Class with PersistenceCapable annotation gets Attempt to store an instance of a non persistable type

Tags: jdo, objectdb

Using ObjectDB
[ObjectDB 2.4.1] javax.jdo.JDOUserException
Attempt to store an instance of a non persistable type com.A

```
@PersistenceCapable
public abstract class B
{
...
@Embedded
protected com.A a = new A();

}
```

Unfortunately we have been using class A from a library for many years and don't have source available anymore and I cannot put PersistenceCapable annotation on com.A.java. What can I do?

Edit

I think the answer is to add package.jdo for class A. But I still don't understand why is JDO making me either add annotation or make an entry in .jdo file for every class that i want to persist. I wish this could somehow be driven by Serializable interface.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization in ObjectDB is disabled by default, in order to encourage using JPA/JDO persistable  types (entity classes, persistence capable classes, embeddable classes), which are more efficient, whenever possible.

However, when serialization is required you can enable it, as explained in the [ObjectDB manual](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/setting/entities#The_persist_element_).

and then you should be able to store instances of serializable instances in your ObjectDB database.